# Getting image out of web browser page C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image, webbrowser-control, html

I am trying to get an image out of a web browser in C#. The whole process goes like this: I load a web page in the web browser. Then I want to get an image out of the webpage, more exactly an html tag(div or span). I tried a couple of ways but none of them seem to work.

webBrowser1.DrawBitmap() does not apply to the webBrowser control.

And the project is a windows forms one, so the web page is not exactly mine to begin with(not and ASP project)

I kept looking for solutions on google and most of them are in Javascript or php, but I need it in C#.

Comment: what do you want to do with the image?

Comment: No further processing will be done to the image. I only want to download it. Like a screenshot. For example of a form or of a div

Answer (score 0):

Use webbrowser to load the page and then parse the html to find the image tag. Use the source to get the image.

Comment: Is this an answer or comment?

Comment: I am not trying to get an actual image(img) tag, but an actual html tag (div, span), just like a screenshot, and then cropping out the actual form or div